# search and replace part of field in multiple records

Tags: mysql, vbulletin

I have translated the table for vbullitin.

An example of content of this record:

> ```
>                                                             | product   | username | dateline | version |
> ```
>
> +----------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+---------+ |   103321 |          2 | usermessage | emailbody | Dit is een bericht
>   van $bbuserinfo[username] van $vboptions[bbtitle] (
>   $vboptions[bburl]/$vboptions[forumhome].php ). De eigenaren van
>   $vboptions[bbtitle] zijn niet verantwoordelijk voor de inhoud van deze
>   e-mail.

The field text contains `$bbuserinfo[username]` I want to change it to `$userinfo[username]` and I want to leave the rest intact .

Is there any way I can update all records with query replacing `$bbuserinfo` with `$userinfo` ?

Comment: Your example record is unreadable, please enter it again. Paste the text from MySQL, then use the `{}` tool to mark it as verbatim text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `REPLACE()` function.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET text = REPLACE(text, '$bbuserinfo', '$userinfo');
```